# Page break in table that uses rowspan

Tags: html, css, page-break

I'm trying to have a page break when printing a table.
I've done this before, but this table doesn't work.
The only difference I see is that this table uses rowspan.
Does rowspan break *page-break-before:always* or something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <style>
        body{
            font-family:"arial";
            font-size:14px;
        }

                @media print{
                    @page {size: landscape}  
                  table tr { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
                  table td { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
                  tr.tableBreak{
                        page-break-before:always !important;    
                        border:2pt solid #000;
                    }  
                    tr.tableBreak td{
                            text-align:center;
                    }
                        
                }       
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    
        <button onclick="window.print()">print</button>
    
      <table id="crTable">
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>2201228506</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/28/2020<br>01/02/2021</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>2201230521</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/30/2020<br>01/04/2021</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>2201230522</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/30/2020<br>01/04/2021</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>2201230526</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/30/2020<br>01/04/2021</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>2201230531</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/30/2020<br>01/04/2021</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>H2O-Faucet-12-27</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/27/2020<br></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class='tableBreak'>
            <td colspan='11'>** SHOULD BE NEW PAGE **</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>H2O-Vat1-12-28</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/28/2020<br></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>H2O-Vat2-12-28</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/28/2020<br></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>H2O-Faucet-12-29</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/29/2020<br></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>H2O-Vat1-12-30</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/29/2020<br></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2' class='cwGreen'>H2O-Vat2-12-30</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>12/29/2020<br></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td class='ctr'>Purple Pink<br>Cocci Rod</td>
            <td class='ctr'>Pos &nbsp;&nbsp; Neg</td>
            <td class='ctr'>____/____</td>
            <td class='ctr'>UI</td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
            <td rowspan='2'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class='crSmall'>date/tech</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      

<p style="page-break-before: always;">test1</p>
<p style="page-break-before: always;">test2</p>      
      
   </body>
</html>
```

In my fiddle I also put a couple P tags just to test the class.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/me7qfu8o/6/)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I never found a solution. 
I ended up re-writing the code to break it up into multiple tables instead of trying to break a single table.